# after an update of wordpress i can no longer login

Tags: php, wordpress

After some research apparently this is caused by white spaces before and after php declaration and closing. I am not sure if that can be the only issue but i have gone over the stated files and removed spaces, made no difference to error.

here is error code, hope its an easy and simple fix.

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /usr/www/users/markekqykk/wp-includes/functions.php:1) in
>   /usr/www/users/markekqykk/wp-login.php on line 431 Warning: Cannot
>   modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at
>   /usr/www/users/markekqykk/wp-includes/functions.php:1) in
>   /usr/www/users/markekqykk/wp-login.php on line 444

on 
wp-login line 431:

```
header('Content-Type: '.get_bloginfo('html_type').';
charset='.get_bloginfo('charset'));
```

on wp-login line 441:

```
setcookie( TEST_COOKIE, 'WP Cookie check', 0, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, $secure );
```

Comment: Rename **plugins** folder in **wp-content** directory to check if some issue is with plugins.

Comment: Still shows same error.

Comment: try to rename themes folder. Also did you enabled error reporting ?

Comment: theme also not changing anything, error reporting is enabled showing the same as web browser.

Answer (score 0):

seems i just replaced the functions.php and all is sorted.